# What does this "!string" mean?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, string, operators

I'm going through an old code library at my workplace to document it and re-use it for other projects. 
The Library isn't documented at all (not even comments) but that's not a big deal.

I found this strange syntax and I can't find an explanation online to what it is...

```
public bool Validate()
    {
        return !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Code) && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(State);
    }
```

I get that the Exclamation point is the negation operator, but it's only possible to use it with Boolean variables. How is it possible to say not(string)? What does that exclamation point before the string keyword does? The tooltip didn't help either..

Comment: Have you checked documentation? `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace` returns a `bool` and `!` is the not operator

Comment: string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Code) is either true or false. So, ! means "not".

Comment: It's not just `!string`, it's `!(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Code))` - just without the extra parentheses.

Comment: See Gilad Greens comment above or my answer below for how '!String' is valid - it's because !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(somestring) is valid not !String itself.

Comment: The downvoting's starting to seem a bit harsh on this - the guy's clearly genuinely not realised that the '!' is applying to the method of string not string itself and to be fair it's not always easy to search for symbols (like exclamation mark) in a search engine, e.g. search for '!string' and you won;t get anything of use.

Comment: And, by De Morgan's Law, this is equivalent `!(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Code) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(State))`, which reads like: valid is the negation of invalid, which is no code or no state.

Comment: The C# reference explains that invocation expressions of member methods take precedence over unary operators: [Expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/expressions#1242-operator-precedence-and-associativity).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

! means not. IsNullOrWhiteSpace is a static method of String which returns a boolean value, so the code is returning whether both 'Code' and 'State' have a value.

Comment: I would also have mentioned precedence, which seems relevant to the original misunderstanding.

Answer (score 2):

That's the standard logical negation operator.

Answer (score 1):

! means `NOT`, as in

```
**Is `Code` is not a NULL or WhiteSpace**
And
**Is `State` is not a NULL or WhiteSpace**
```